# plug np.array into sympy expression

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I need to subs a numpy.array into an indexed symbol of Sympy expression to numerically calculate the sum. (1+2+3+4+5=15).
My below code still produce symbolic expression. Please help~

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
i = Symbol("i")
y = Symbol("y")
y_ = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
h = Sum(Indexed("y","i"),(i,0,4))
h.subs([(y,y_)])
```

Comment: show some of the expressions,

Comment: The symbol `y`, is not the same as the Indexed `y[i]`.  They may look related, but they have no connection.  As a general rull, using `numpy` and `sympy` does not work well.  The best tool is to use `sympy.lambdify` to generate a numpy compatible function.

Answer (score 2):

smichr answer is solid, however considering that the numerical values of `h_` are going to be converted by SymPy to symbolic numbers, the easiest and fastest way is to do this:

```
new_h = h.subs(y, Array(y_))
# out: Sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5][i], (i, 0, 4))
# alternatively:
# new_h = h.subs(y, sympify(y_))
new_h.doit()
# out: 15
```

Another alternative is to convert your symbolic expression to a numerical function with `lambdify`. However, this approach works as long as the there is not infinity on the bounds of the summation:

```
f = lambdify([y], h)
f(y_)
# out: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this will work?

```py
>>> y = IndexedBase("y")
>>> h = Sum(y[i],(i,0,4));h.doit()
y[0] + y[1] + y[2] + y[3] + y[4]
>>> _.subs(dict(zip([y[i] for i in range(len(y_))],y_)))
15
```